# Constant credit card fraud - is this normal?

Tags: credit-card, banking, credit, fraud

I have a Chase Sapphire credit card that has only two authorized users: myself and my husband. We are the only ones who have the card. We both use the cards safely following the "rules". I pay using the chip whenever merchants allow it (99% of the time the merchants tell me I need to swipe, but that's another matter).

Despite all that, our card seems to be having fraudulent charges made on it *extremely* often. In the last few months, I've gotten 6 or 7 replacement cards with new numbers each time. Each time the fraudulent charge is made to a Starbucks Card Reload. I literally have no time to learn my card number when a new one needs to be sent to me.

I have spoken to a manager at the credit card company who assured me I was doing nothing wrong but could unfortunately do nothing about it. I have never heard of anyone having this amount of fraudulent charges, though. Is this a normal but unfortunate tough-luck kind of situation, or is this something that needs to be dealt with another way?

Comment: Its not limited to Chase.  I am currently going through something similar, and it is with a different bank.

Comment: If you store the credit card information online or use the same password on your bank as on any other site, worth checking https://haveibeenpwned.com/ to see if your authentication details have been leaked.

Answer (score 6):

There are two options:

1. You routinely use it with a merchant who has an employee that steals card numbers. If you have regular purchases in a physical store/gas station/restaurant - consider using a different *credit* card for each store and see where the fraudulent charges appear. That way you'll know who's the guilty party.
2. Similarly it may happen online and a merchant has a leak/breach.

You can also file a police report, although they will probably not do much unless tons of reports start accumulating from a specific area (case #1), then they'll probably investigate.

Comment: And if you don't have enough credit cards to use a different one in each place you can use a different card on one place at a time.  When you get a new card pick one business to test and wait for the next breech.  If it's still the Chase card switch your test to the next business, repeat until you find the culprit.